# Loop to calculate percentage several times Java

Tags: java, bluej

Using the `infections` and the `percent` that are in the second method, let's say I have the numbers 169(infections) and 25(percent), so the **result is** 42.25, now, 169-42.25=**126.25**. I wanna know how long does it take for the incidence(that 169) value to **drop below 50**, assuming that it decreases by a certain percentage (this case 25)*each week*. Let's say I had to take that percentage 9 times until the 169 became 49(e.g). Those nine times would represent **9 weeks** which is why I'm looking for.

In the code part `public double incidenceDevelopment`, what I do is calculate the percentage, then with the `do-while` I tried to calculate the percentage until it became 50 or less and then return the variable, but it does not work. ***My question is how can I do that***

```
public class incidence {

private int residents;

incidence() {
    residents = 235723;
}

public double calculateIncidence(double infections) {
    double inz;
    inz = infections / residents * 100000;
    return inz;
}

public double incidenceDevelopment(double infections, int percent) {
    double duration;
    duration = infections * percent / 100;
    duration = infections - duration;
    do {
        duration = duration * percent / 100;
        duration = infections - duration;
    } while (duration <= 50);
    return duration;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is an improved code , I think you wanted to do this ( count *durations* in weeks while *infections* drop by a *percent* .)

```
public class incidence {

private int residents;

incidence() {
    residents = 235723;
}

public double calculateIncidence(double infections) {
    double inz;
    inz = infections / residents * 100000;
    return inz;
}

public double incidenceDevelopment(double infections, int percent) {
    double duration;
    duration = infections * percent / 100;
    infections= infections - duration;
    do {
        duration = duration * percent / 100;
        infections = infections - duration;
    } while (duration > 50);
    return duration;
}
```

Comment: The answer is coming 10.5625 in your example of 169 infections and 25 percentage

Comment: Exactly! That is what I am trying to do. But there is something wrong still, as working with the numbers "273" infections and "30%", the result must be 8(weeks), but I get 24.57 and I do not what it is wrong

Comment: Can you explain how you got 8 in first place ? @AaronMartinez